# <compiler-generated> line 0 tableViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)

Tags: swift

I'm receiving fabric crash on tableview controller. The fabric have following crash trace & I'm not able to reproduce it in development and testing phase.

```
<compiler-generated> line 0
tableViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)
```

Please see the screenshot.

code for cellforrow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for : indexPath) as? customCell  else {
        print("custom cell are not set")
        return UITableViewCell()

    }
cell.NameLabel.Text = list[indexPath.row].name ?? "" 
.
.
.
return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Share cellforrow() code.

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman Please see the updated question with code

Comment: you are using pull down to refresh functionality or not ?

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman in some tableviewController but not in this, these crash occur on both case, pull to refresh and without any pull to refresh functionality, and 
I'm using "KRPullLoader" for loading more data in tableview for few tableviewcontrollers.

Comment: Hi @JibranSiddiQui, did you find a solution on this?